# jQuery/HTML Operate on the found element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first question here. 
First of all, please see this bit of code.

```
 $('#btn').click(function () {
 if ($(this).parent().find('a').attr('href') == $("#search_list").find('a').attr('href')) {
  $(secondelement).css(.......) ///any operation.
 }
 });
```

My question is how to perform an operation on the found/matched/second element? In this case, the element 'a' in #search_list having href equal to the href of 'a' in #btn's parent.

Comment: Store a reference to the element first? `var aElements =  $("#search_list").find('a');`. Note that `$("#search_list").find('a').attr('href')` will *always* get the `href` value of the **first** `a` element in `#search_list`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You would have to post the relevant markup (HTML).

Comment: @FelixKling No Felix. I want to go through all the 'a' elements in #search_list and when there is an 'a' who's href is equal to the provided one, i want to perform an operation on that.

Comment: That's not really what you're currently doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is

```
$(this).parent().find('a').attr('href') == $("#search_list").find('a').attr('href')
```

it gets the href attribute of the first found anchor in the parent and compares against the first found anchor inside `#search_list` (`attr` will return the attribute for the first element in the collection).

To get the same element, you can use the attributes selector instead, and select the first anchor in `#search_list` if it has the same href as the first anchor in the parent.

EDIT: to get any anchor with the same href as the first anchor in the parent element, you'd do :

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
    $('#search_list a[href="' + $(this).parent().find('a').attr('href') + '"]').css('color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: That's not what the original code does though ;) (maybe you want to expand on that).

Comment: @FelixKling - it is now ?

Comment: I guess... though I wonder whether `a[href=...]` isn't actually what the OP really wants.